# okhttp. Can't save loaded data

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I can't save data loaded from okhttp. What is wrong in my code. When I try to load data on Log app crashes. Please Help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String URL = "https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/search/titles/results/?terms=michigan&format=json&page=5";
private String data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadData();
    Log.d("DATA", data);
}

private void loadData() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URL)
            .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            data = response.body().string();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: "When I try to load data on Log app crashes." - This is too broad.  Is there an error/exception?

Comment: Its Null pointer exception even though the response is being return.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: What exception have you got? Add your error log in your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

The problem is around how your code is being executed (i.e sync vs async).

You call the method `loadData()` which will not set the class attribute data as you're expecting - it will set the attribute `data` once it gets a response however that function `loadData` will not wait for the response (i.e it doesn't block the current thread or execution code.) . Which means on the next line `LOG.d("Data", data);`, data has not been set, thus is null (and will crash your app).

### Solution

If you just want to LOG data, then just move your log statement after you assign it on your onResponse callback.

```
private void loadData() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URL)
            .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            // Some error has occurred
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {   
            processData(response.body().string());
        }
    });
}

private void processData(String data) {
    Log.d("DATA", data);
    // To other stuff here given your value data. 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But what should I do to be able to access it from class level.

Comment: My suggestion is that you don't have a reference to data at your class level. just pass it to another function. ie.

Comment: You shoud have a method `handleData(String data)` and call it from the `onResponse` callback